# Trig Equation - 2 years out of math & lost

Tags: trigonometry

$$\cos^2(2x) + \sin^4(x) = 2$$

So lost on how to solve these things and it's already midnight. 3 days I've spent reviewing and doing practice, but I can't find any proper information on how to go about this.

I figured I would try and break $\cos^2(2x)$ down into $2\cos^2(x)$ but I can't determine if that was the way it was done?

Edit: I am simply trying to figure out how to do this. I recall one of my professors explaining how to break cos^2(2x) down...

Comment: $|sin(x)|\leq 1$, $|cos(x)|\leq 1$ so in order to sum up to 2 each term on left hand side must be 1.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it makes pleas of urgency.

Comment: And because nobody has said it, unfortunately you cannot just take the $2$ out of $\cos^2(2x)$ like that. The brackets there are just to tell you what is the input into the function $\cos$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment by frankoo gives by far the best approach. It is important to *think* about a problem before starting to manipulate. But if you want to use identities, you could proceed as follows.

Note that $\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2(x)$. Squaring, we obtain
$$4\sin^4 x-4\sin^2 x+1+\sin^4 x=2.$$ 
This simplifies to $5\sin^4 x-4\sin^2 x-1=0$.  Rewrite as $(5\sin^2 x+1)(\sin^2 x-1)=0$. The equation $5\sin^2 x+1=0$ has no real solution, so the solutions are given by $\sin x=\pm 1$. Thus the solutions are $x=\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi$ and $x=-\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi$, where $n$ ranges over the integers.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating on how to incorporate the square appropriately!! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

As $\cos2x=1-2\sin^2x,$ write $\sin^2x=\dfrac{1-\cos2x}2$ to form a Quadratic Equation in $\cos2x$